# Magento with and c# Call Object

Tags: c#, php, magento, compact-framework

I am developing a simple application for a WinCE5 mobile device using Magneto. I am very new to Magento. I have managed to perform the login without a hitch and receive the session id.

The issue I am having right now is to receive the Associative Array from the Server using c#.

Here is a sample PHP Code

```php
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://someurl.com/index.php/api/soap?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('username', 'password');
$result = $client->call($session, 'traveldoc.getStatusOptions', null);
var_dump($result);
$client->endSession($session);
?>
```

And here is the output

> array(9) { ["Item_1"]=> string(5) "apple" ["Item_2"]=> string(6) "Banana" ["Item_3"]=> string(14) "Watermelon"  }

I am trying to replicate this in C#. I manage to get the session return but the Mg_client.call is an object. How do I retrieve the array as I did in PHP? The array format is fixed.

```c#
MagentoSer.MagentoService MG_client = new MagentoSer.MagentoService();
session = MG_client.login("username", "password");
object myResult = MG_client.call(session, "traveldoc.getStatusOptions", null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't seem to find the API reference, so I'm not sure I can help you. You should know what type of object MG_client.Call(...) returns.. What is it? You can then turn it into what you want... does this library not have a reference? What does GetType() return?

Comment: It somehow returns a class type. I notice that if I use at standard string array I am able to cast it as string[]. But when I get the Associative array I cannot cast it as any Type even dictionary or keyvaluepair.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not C# developer, but I think it should be somethnig like this:

```
Result[] array = new MG_client.call(session, "traveldoc.getStatusOptions", null);
```

Comment: not working as MG_client.call is a public object. It can't be converted to an array. I have tried myResult.GetType().IsArray and it returns false.

Comment: Try to use SOAP API V2 - http://www.exampledomain.com/shop/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl also here is example for C# http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/web_services/using_soap_api_in_c_sharp